# RadWindow PopUp from CodeBehind from RadGrid Dropdownlist(EditMode)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, radgrid, radwindow

I have a situation that I need some answers for please. I am working with the RadWindow control using the Contenttemplate. When my RadGrid is in EditMode, and user makes a selection from a contained dropdownlist, I would like to PopUp the RadWindow at that point showing user adding  options to help further filter data. When user clicks to close the Radwindow, I want to return to my EditMode RadGrid displaying the selected options in my RadGrid Textbox.

My question is, how do I get my radwindow(content template) to display from codebehind.

```
 <telerik:RadWindow ID="UserListDialog" runat="server" Title="Editing record" Width="250"  Height="536" KeepInScreenBounds="true" Modal="true"
                            Behaviors="Minimize, Move, Resize, Maximize" Left="580" Top="-8" EnableShadow="true">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel ID="PnlUserRoleList">
                                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="UserRoleCheckBoxList" runat="server" Width="60%" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddselected" Text="AddItems" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadWindow>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution close to your scenario in an old Telerik forum thread (view it [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/update-with-external-button.aspx)). The client code seems to be obsolete and you probably have to convert/adopt it for the ajax version of the controls and your case, but still it can be a good start.